# How to call a element from Layout without use findViewId() in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

I didn't know this was possible, but I was following an example and I see this piece of code:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    toggleButtonGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener { toggleButtonGroup, checkedId, isChecked ->
    //some code here 
    }
}
```

Here is the code:
https://gist.github.com/smartherd/0803ba4e287d6aa0d441d0a221eeb013

"toggleButtonGroup" is the ID of the element in layout, and he doesn´t declare it anywhere in the MainActivity, how can I do this?

Comment: The synthetic extensions (in your import there) are deprecated, you shouldn't use them. It basically does some magic and creates a fake variable for each view ID in the layout your Activity is using, so you can just access them without declaring them and looking up the views. If you want this kind of thing, you should use View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) which generates all the ID references on a binding object instead

Comment: More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236873/why-do-i-get-unresolved-reference-error-for-my-views-name-id-when-i-type-it-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you saw is `Kotlin synthetics` and has been `deprecated` in favor of `ViewBinding` and is heavily discouraged to use. You should use `ViewBinding` instead.

Enable `ViewBinding` for your project by setting `viewBinding` build feature to `true`, inside your module-level `build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    ...
}
```

By enabling this, Android studio will start generating `viewBinding` classes for your `layouts`.

---

Using `ViewBinding` inside an `activity`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        //here access your view using binding
        binding.toggleButtonGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener { toggleButtonGroup, checkedId, isChecked ->
                //some code here 
        }    
    }
}
```

`ActivityMainBinding` is the `class` generated by Android Studio using the `activity_main` layout.

---

Using `ViewBinding` inside a `fragment`

```
class TestFragment: Fragment() {

    private var _binding: TestFragmentBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = TestFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        return view
    }
    
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()

        //setting _binding to null is important to avoid any memory leaks
        _binding = null 
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your time, it works, thank you. Just a little bit more information, why I can't access to the addOnButtonCheckedListener from a variable created with the classic method? Using findviewid this method doesn't exist