# Kotlin Cannot Inflate Layout

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am building an application that has a `GridView` that contains a dynamic amount of `CardView`s.  I am having issues accessing the `TextView` elements in the individual items layout from the custom adapter that I am creating.

`tvCastleName` and `tvShieldTime` are unresolved references, and the application will not compile.

**main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNickname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Nickname"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvNickname"
        android:horizontalSpacing="6dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="6dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:id="@+id/gvCastles" />
```

**items.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCastleName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="Castle Name"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCastleName"
            android:text="15:00"
            android:id="@+id/tvShieldTime"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**GridAdapter.kt**

```kt
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter

class GridAdapter(var nameList: ArrayList<Castle>, var context: Context?) : BaseAdapter() {


  override fun getCount(): Int = nameList.size

  override fun getItem(position: Int): Castle = nameList[position]

  override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
  }

  override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val nameList = this.nameList[position]
    var inflater = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val castleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, null)
    castleView.tvCastleName.text = nameList.name!!
    castleView.tvShieldTime.text = "15:00"
    
    return castleView
  }

}
```

Comment: I am following the tutorial here as the results in the video are what I am trying to achieve: https://youtu.be/EIariByWjMo
I am also aware that inflation techniques have changed to view binding, but I am unable to make anything work.  Currently my files are in a state that mimics what is found in the video.

Comment: The name obviously is `R.id.tvCastleName`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler you are correct.  I edited the post (and my live files).  We are still left with the same issue.

Comment: This part here also appears useless: `getItemId(position: Int): Long = 0`; you may want to return different IDs.

Comment: @MartinZeitler also correct.  It is basically a "to do" item once things are more operational.  :)

Comment: Not exactly, because without an unique ID, there is no way of properly telling them apart. When it's lots of items, I'd rather use a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I agree with you.  However, irrelevant to the question posted, correct?

Comment: Not at all ...because when the adapter cannot really tell apart it's items, everything which depends on the adapter being able to tell apart these items will subsequently also fail. You might still be able to add them into the adapter alike that, but then it gets problematic.

Comment: Take a look at the video posted in my first comment.  Skip forward to 5:38.  She is implementing the inflater there, but has yet to implement `getItemId`.  Her inflation works.  The inflation not resolving is a separate issue.  However, I will edit my post now.

Comment: I think the issue has to do with a) these ID and b) `inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, parent)`.

Comment: While I agree with the problem that you are stating regarding the `getItemId` function, I disagree that it is relevant to my issue.  My issue is a compile time issue. The references are unresolved. The issue that you describing, while true, would be a runtime issue.  It would certainly cause problems, but only once I am able to get the application to compile and run successfully. You are knowledgeable, certainly, but, respectfully, we are off track here. You are correct that the `inflate` call is the issue here. I just need to figure out how to resolve it. I have been pounding my head over it.

Comment: The tutorial you are following is an old tutorial that is using `kotlin synthetics` which has been deprecated a long time ago and is discouraged to use now. You aren't able to access views in your project as you don't have the `synthetics` plugin enabled in your project. You should use `viewBinding` to access views instead. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72234410/11983124

Comment: @Praveen thank you. I agree, and actually use view binding in two activities in this project. I just haven't been able to make it work in this custom adapter. What changes would I have to make in order for it to work in the adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be getting `Unresolved Reference` as the method (`Kotlin Synthetics`) you are using to access `view` is now `deprecated`. You can use `ViewBinding` to access your `views`.

You've to make a few changes to your `getItem` method, to make it work with `ViewBinding`

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val nameList = this.nameList[position]
    val itemsBinding = ItemsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    itemsBinding.tvCastleName.text = nameList.name!!
    itemsBinding.tvShieldTime.text = "15:00"        
    return itemsBinding.root
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I believe this is working.  I have another (similar) issue that is giving me issues at runtime, but I believe your solution is working!  I will mark this one as answer once I sort through this last little bit.

Comment: I sorted out my other issue and have fully verified that your solution is working.  I have marked your solution as answer.  Thank you again! Absolutely wonderful!