# 'kotlin-android-extensions' gradle plugin is no longer supported

Tags: kotlin

I got 'kotlin-android-extensions' gradle plugin is no longer supported on Android Studio while coding in Kotlin language. How can i solve it? I've tried the solutions on the internet. However they did not work. Please help me.

I have a text with 'textView' id and i a button with 'degistir' onClick method. I want my program be able to change the text when i clicl the button. I have this function in this manner.

`fun degistir(view: View){ textView.text = "Merhaba Android" } }`

But textView gives error, i can not import it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236873/why-do-i-get-unresolved-reference-error-for-my-views-name-id-when-i-type-it-i