# Why can't I access view IDs directly in RecyclerView.ViewHolder?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm developing an Android app using RecyclerView, and I'm trying to access view IDs directly in my ViewHolder class. According to the documentation, this seems to be possible:

"A ViewHolder describes an item view and metadata about its place within the RecyclerView.

Adapter implementations should subclass ViewHolder and add fields for caching potentially expensive results."

However, when attempting to access the views directly, I receive errors. The relevant code is as follows:

```kotlin
class AnimalAdapter(val animals: MutableList<Animal>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AnimalAdapter.AnimalViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AnimalViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.animal_card, parent, false)
        return AnimalViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = animals.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AnimalViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(animals[position])
    }

      inner class AnimalViewHolder(itemView: View) : 
          RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
          // Setting direct references (causes errors)
          // itemView.txt_animal_id = 
          itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_animal_id)
    
          // Using findViewById (works, but seems unnecessary)
          val animalIdTextView: TextView = 
                              itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_animal_id)
          val calvingDateTextView: TextView = 
                           itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_calving_date)
           // ... other references ...
    
          fun bind(animal: Animal) {
                // This generates an error
                // itemView.txt_animal_id.text = animal.animalID
        
                // This works, but seems redundant
                animalIdTextView.text = animal.animalID
                // ... other updates ...
          }
     }
}
```

The documentation suggests that this should work. What might be causing the error? Is there a way to enable direct access to view IDs, or is this no longer supported in newer versions of Android Studio?

I appreciate any help or clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't enable direct access, and in this part of the documentation you quoted:

> and **add fields** for caching potentially expensive results

"add fields" means you have to do it. It's not automatic. I don't see anything in the documentation you quoted suggesting that fields are generated automatically for you.

Directly accessing views by name is something that used to be supported a few years ago with an extension called `kotlin-android-extensions` which is deprecated an no longer works with recent versions of Kotlin. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236873/why-do-i-get-unresolved-reference-error-for-my-views-name-id-when-i-type-it-i) for more information about that.

There is an alternate way to easily get your views by name, called [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) that is the recommended way to do it.

In your code, your after enabling View Binding in Gradle according to the instructions linked above, your ViewHolder could look like:

```
inner class AnimalViewHolder(itemView: View) : 
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    private val viewBinding = AnimalCardBinding.bind(itemView)

    fun bind(animal: Animal) = viewBinding.apply {
          // You can directly access views by name in here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I was following an older tutorial where direct access to views by name was more straightforward. I appreciate your clarification about the recent changes in Kotlin and the suggestion of View Binding as an alternative. I will consider this approach for my project. Thanks again!